# How to write condition in sightly template?

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem, sightly, htl

Does sightly template render based on a condition?

e.g.
component.html render based on arguments

if argument one exist

```
<div data-sly-use.myComponent="${'com.myproject.service' @ param1='one''}">
    ${myComponent.calculatedValue}
</div>
```

if argument two exist

```
<div data-sly-use.myComponent="${'com.myproject.service' @ param2='one''}"">
    ${myComponent.calculatedValue}
</div>
```

if argument doesn't exist

```
<div data-sly-use.myComponent="${'com.myproject.MyComponent'}">
    ${myComponent.calculatedValue}
</div>
```

Question 2: How to get param1='one' value (from javascript or jsp)

Question 3: is it possible to do string operation on this value ${myComponent.calculatedValue}

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rendering in HTL/Sightly is possible by using `data-sly-test` (see [SPEC](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#225-test)):

```
<div data-sly-test="${param1 == 'one'}"..>..</div>
<div data-sly-test="${param2 == 'one'}"..>..</div>
<div data-sly-test="${param1 != 'one' && param2 != 'one'}"..>..</div>
```

This allows you to instantiate different Use Objects based on a parameter. The parameter must be defined inline, accessed via the available bindings/[global objects](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/global-objects.html) or via another Use Object.

Operations are [not supported](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#112-expressions) in HTL expressions at this moment.

Comment: how to pass these value in data-sly-use line